# Validation Please: Google Web Fonts + Google Chrome 11.0.696.68 + Windows 7 + text-shadow (with rgba) = Fail

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, google-webfonts, css

Doing a bit of research, it appears Google Chrome renders the rest of the page, but until the web font has loaded, it displays a blank space in place of the text that uses the font [source: http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/technical_considerations.html#Browser_Behavior]. However, when users with Chrome 11.0.696.68 on Windows 7 display Google Web Fonts with text-shadows that have any rgba alpha value other than 1 the Google Web Font never renders. All other browsers render the code accurately. Even Chrome 11.0.696.68 on OSX renders the code correctly. Could someone please validate that the test case below does not work in Google Chrome on Windows 7. Please list if you find a version of Chrome on Windows 7 that works with the test case below.

Here is my test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unkempt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background:#808080; }
        p { font:40px 'Unkempt', sans-serif; color:#fff; }
        .rgba_t { text-shadow:0px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.99); }
        .rgba_1 { text-shadow:0px -1px rgba(0,0,0,1); }
        .hex { text-shadow:0px -1px #030303; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="rgba_t">Unkempt text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.99)</p>
        <p class="rgba_1">Unkempt text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1)</p>
        <p class="hex">Unkempt text-shadow: #030303</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should come back to SO, we miss you! (Or at least I do, as you can upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows 7 64bit, Chrome 12.0.742.., and the shadow one does not work for me either. [image]